# Why R is changing decimal numbers in an input

Tags: microsoft-excel, r

I´m reading a excel file with readWorksheetFromFile from XLConnect library, but it seems like R is adding some different decimals in the last part of number, 
I think this error is not from the read excel function because when I write 51171.556554598111 and hit intro the last decimals places looks changed like that -> [1] 51171.556554598108

Answer (score 1):

*Excel store 15 significant digits of precision.*
*The IEEE 754 floating-point standard requires that numbers be stored in binary format.*

From [Microsoft.com (blog 4/2008): Understanding Floating Point Precision aka Why Does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)

See also [Microsoft.com (help 4/2018): Floating Point Arithmetic May Give Inaccurate Results In Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel)

Comment: Please refrain from link-only answers. Be sure to check out the [answer section](https://superuser.com/help/answering) to get some helpful tips on how to write the best answers.

Comment: *The IEEE 754 floating-point standard requires that numbers be stored in binary format* that's definitely incorrect. There are [IEEE-754 decimal formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)

Comment: My answer fill short of the standard here. The text was simply two quotes from a blog on Microsoft.com detailing the reason for the oddity raised by the question. I stand corrected on the point of binary encoding being required. Much has already been written on this subject and my brevity was with this in mind.